# Using stainless braided line with AN fitting and connecting it to junction block

Tags: brakes, brake-lines

I am attempting to do something new, and after researching about it, I am still heavily confused. I have watched multiple videos on how the AN fittings actually go on the braided lines, which makes sense, but my confusion stems from how you get them on to the caliper side and the junction block. I have just put on a rear disc brake conversion kit and it came with a banjo bolt setup which would work seamlessly with a normal metal line setup, you would just flare it. Realistically, I want to get rid of the existing line for the banjo bolt and just use braided stainless line all the way to the banjo bolt. 
I got -3 (Hose Size) 3/16 (tubing size) braided brake line from: https://www.pegasusautoracing.com/productselection.asp?Product=3260 
They recommend their own 3AN Hose End: https://www.pegasusautoracing.com/productdetails.asp?RecID=4154 
Beyond this, how do I even get that into the junction block itself, and how can I get rid of the existing line from the caliper that has the banjo bolt? 
[image]&hm=82ea79ce72f3cfd0c03110f2c2d7504a0a6d1b84f897a1ecac6252829a5e9384&

This is the braided brake line itself.
[image]
This is the banjo bolt that goes into the caliper.
[image]
Lastly, this is the other side of the line that came with the rear disc brake conversion kit, that would normally be used with a flared metal line.

Answer (score 0):

For the banjo end, don’t you just want one of their banjo fittings that they sell on the same website for their stainless braided hose, for example -

[Banjo fittings](https://www.pegasusautoracing.com/group.asp?GroupID=SSBRAKEFITTING)

[image]

Have you searched on their website for the other fittings you need?

Comment: yes but how would this work, that fitting picture would work with a flared metal line, the inside of the braided line is not metal, but some sort of hard plastic.

Comment: It says in the text - This stainless steel banjo hose end fitting is designed to work with our -3 PTFE Lined Stainless Braided Hose (Part No. 3260-3, sold separately). It is easily installed in the field without any special tooling required.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Would I just put the line into the banjo fitting? No flare required? How would it actually seal

Comment: The hard plastic inside the braided stainless his cover may be nylon or other plastic designed to withstand high pressure hydraulic brake systems (several hundred psi). The banjo fitting may match the hose but most likely needs machine crimping. It may be wise to call or email the site for expertise in custom making brake lines.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that the hexagonal part unscrews, you remove it, push the pipe on, then screw it back on.  The pipe gets squashed and seals in place. As it says, no special tools are needed.